# JavaScript langCode

Tags: javascript

I want to use this piece of JavaScript so that, depending on the browser language of the visitor, a specific page is shown. The default should be English, so if the language isn´t one of the 5 languages that are set in the script, it should automatically select English. At the moment, it doesn´t seem to do so. Can anyone modify this piece of code for me so that it does just that?

```
var langcodes = ["es", "ca", "en" ,"nl", "fr", "de"];
var langCode = navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage;
var lang = langCode.toLowerCase();
lang = lang.substr(0,2);
var dest = window.location.href;
for (i = langcodes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (lang == langcodes[i]) {
        dest = dest.substr(0,dest.lastIndexOf('.')) + '-' + lang.substr(0,2) +
            dest.substr(dest.lastIndexOf('.'));
        window.location.replace ?
            window.location.replace(dest) :
            window.location=dest;
    }
}
```

Comment: [JScript !== JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jscript/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick turnarounnd without looping and if/else would be,

```
var langCode = navigator.language || navigator.systemLanguage;
var lang = langCode.toLowerCase();
lang = lang.substr(0,2);

var langs = {
"es" : "xyz.com/es.html",
"ca": "xyz.com/ca.html",
"nl": "xyz.com/nl.html",
"en": "xyz.com/en.html"
}

if(typeof langs[lang] == 'undefined'){
window.location = "xyz.com/en.html";
}
else{
window.location = langs[lang];
}
```